# How to set file permission to 777 using umask

Tags: files, permissions, ls, umask

It is true that i may not have understood how `umask` calculations work.

This query is just for a test case (my learning).

My intention is that my process should generate a file pdf `file1.pdf` with full permission `777` however, it generates a maximum of `666` permissions only.

```
#!/bin/bash
export umask=111;
echo "Tomcat is starting .... "
 rm file1.pdf
 umask 111
 echo "Hello" >file1.pdf
 echo "Tomcat started"
```

Output post run:

```
root@6b5c5e56c544:/tmp/exersize# ls -ltr file1.pdf
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 6 Aug  5 15:22 file1.pdf
```

Can you please explain as a layman why cant I set file permissions to 777 and how I can?

Comment: A plain pdf file does not need execute bit.  Is there a reason for you to add x permission to the pdf file?  Also, you'll need to set `umask` to 000.

Comment: umask doesn't control the permissions bits.  The process that creates the file requests the permissions, and the umask can force some of the bits off.  However, umask can't force any of the bits on.  You can have a umask value of `000` which allows all permissions bits to be on, but if the process doesn't request some of the bits on, they won't be on.